# "Could not find schema information for element" - warning message, what does it mean?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, deployment, xsd

Within the AppManifest.xml I'm getting two similar warning messages, just trying to distinguish what they mean?

- Could not find schema information for the element
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment:Deployment.Parts'
- Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment:Deployment'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This is incorrect - trying to understand more from OP]
It would help if you post your wmappmanifest.xml file.

Try the following: Change your scheme from what you have, to the following:

> http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment

Comment: Sorry - I misread your original post. Tell me - what's the build action on the AppManifest? It should be "None". Also, does this happen when you start a new Silverlight application project (the same error I mean)?

Comment: Nope, doesn't happen with any other application I create, weird huh?

Comment: So is the build action on the AppManifest "None"?